# IPtables rules bad arguments

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to write IPtables rules,but I'm finding it difficult.

I've got:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state –state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

which fails with Bad argument `–state'

and

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT –to server.ip
```

which fails with Bad argument `–to'

How do I rectify the rules?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Long form options require two `-` [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) characters, not one, and it doesn't allow a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) `–`.  So use `--state` instead of `-state`.  Perhaps your text editor is converting a double `--` to a dash `–`?  Do not use Word, Wordpad, or some other office product for editing, they almost always try to automatically make changes like this for you.  Use a text editor like vi, emacs, nano, notepad++/notepad/etc, or anything else designed for scripting or programming.

Comment: I still long for the day when SF implements the "long upvote" that is equivalent to two, or maybe 10-15, upvotes.  "Text editors" that correct `--` to an m-dash are an abomination!